# HTTP Security Headers in wp-config

Tags: security, headers

Is there a way to place the HTTP Security Headers in `wp-config.php` instead of in `.htaccess` or `functions.php`? If so, what is the format?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a very good idea from the point of security. Could you explain a little bit more what you are trying to achieve by doing this.

Comment: I want to create a script to automatically check if these headers are set (among other security recommendations) and if not, set them. The wp-config.php file seems simpler to deal with compared to .htaccess and funtions.php. Also, the .htacess may be protected. I know there are plugins already for this but I would like to do this at least as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file is read by the Apache server software before it even hands over to WordPress to generate a page. It is by far the best place to have your security headers.

That said, WordPress does have a [class to modify the headers](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/send_headers/) before they are send to the browser. This class [contains a filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_headers/) which you could use in a plugin. Beware that this filter might be bypassed if your page is served by a caching plugin (or some server level form of caching).

The `wp-config.php` file has a fairly narrow scope, [as you can see in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php). Defining security headers there is not among the possibilities.

Bottom line: yes, there are some ways to set security headers within WordPress, but make sure your `.htaccess` is in order.

Answer (score 3):

The `wp-config.php` file is not a good place to put the headers but in case that you do not have access to `.htaccess` or you are in Nginx server that you are not allowed to modify config, you can put this in your theme's `functions.php` or a plugin:

## Modifying WP headers via wp_headers filter

```
function additional_headers( $headers ) {   if ( ! is_admin() ) {

  $headers['Referrer-Policy']             = 'no-referrer-when-downgrade';
  $headers['X-Content-Type-Options']      = 'nosniff';
  $headers['X-XSS-Protection']            = '1; mode=block';
  $headers['Permissions-Policy']          = 'geolocation=(self "https://example.com") microphone=() camera=()';
  $headers['Content-Security-Policy']     = 'script-src "self"';
  $headers['X-Frame-Options']             = 'SAMEORIGIN';   }

  return $headers; 
}
  
add_filter( 'wp_headers', 'additional_securityheaders' );
```